# Se puede hacer una función de IF para números pares e impares?

Tags: php, condiciones

me pidieron que hicieran un algoritmo en PHP donde el usuario ingrese 5 números y me diga si son pares o no.Yo sé como hacerlo pero tendría que hacer una formula por cada uno así que he investigado y sé que  se pueden crear funciones para ahorrar código, sin embargo, a mi no me ha funcionado T.T y ya lo he intentando de mil maneras y nada.

Alguien me puede ayudar ? LO HICE SOLAMENTE CON 1 PARA AHORRAR  TIEMPO PORQUE ANTES LO HICE CON LOS 5 Y ME MARCABAN ERRORES.

```
<h3>  NUMEROS PARES E IMPARES  </h3>

Digite 1 numeros:=<input type="text" name="num1">
 <br></br>  

<input type="submit" value ="Oprima aqui"/>;

<?php

function Par (){
if ($num1%2==0)
echo "par";
else 
echo "impar";
      }

Par();

?>
```

y al final me sale

> Notice: Undefined variable: num1 in *****.

Por fa ayudenme , ya he intentado de mil maneras el codigo pero nada , ya he visto videos pero nada, se que es algo básico pero la verdad no le veo por donde. Denme un tip o algo por donde iniciar y lo intentare ;C

Comment: Te falta asignar el valor del input a la variable $num1, pues esta aislados el uno del otro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas:

- Necesitas asignar el parametro a la funcion Par(), necesitas saber que numero quieres comprobar si es par o no.
- Necesitas crear un form para pasarle la variable que envies (esto lo puedes hacer $_POST['input_name'] siendo input name el attributo name del input.
- Necesitas comprobar que has enviado el valor en el formulario, esto lo puedes hacer con la funcion isset.

  ```
  <h3>  NUMEROS PARES E IMPARES  </h3>
  <form method="post" action="/"> 
  Digite 1 numeros:=<input type="text" name="num1">
   <br></br>  

  <input type="submit" value ="Oprima aqui"/>;
  </form>
  <?php


  function Par($num1) {
    if ($num1%2==0) {
      echo "par";
    } else {
     echo "impar";
    }
  }

  if (isset($_POST['num1'])) {
     Par($_POST['num1']);
  }

  ?>
  ```

Comment: Gracias Miguel pérez, me ayudaste un monton ahora entiendo cual fue mi problema U.U.